# AngualrJS - controller as syntax in component broke functionality

Tags: angularjs, components

I am working with AngularJS 1.5. I am writing a component and if I stick with the $ctrl syntax my component works but if I try to use controllerAs it doesn't work.

```
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .component('attachments', {
            bindings: {
                add: '&',
                remove: '&',
                attachments: '<'
            },
            templateUrl: 'bookAbsence/attachments/attachments.html',
            controller: 'AttachmentsController'
        });

})();
```

vs controllerAs 'attachments'

html

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.canUploadAttachment === true">
    <add-attachment-button add="$ctrl.handleAdd(value)"></add-attachment-button>
    <attachment-list attachments="$ctrl.attachments" remove="$ctrl.handleRemove(value)"></attachment-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Share a plunkr with that code. Let me see how you are invoking it. Cant help much with the code provided above

Comment: You are overloading the word `attachments`. You use it as a component name. And an attribute name. Now you want to use it as a "controllerAs" name. Insane.